# Ansible 2.0 upgrade - default filter chain error

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Prior to Ansible 2.0, default filters were allowed

```
"{{ oracle1.instance.reports|d().forecast|d().email|d('testing@gmail.com') }}"
```

where `|d()` would allow a variable (such as `reports` or `forecast`) to be defaulted to the default variable at the end (in this case, the default variable is `testing@gmail.com`) if the program couldn't find an instance for `reports` or `forecast`. `reports` & `forecasts` are defined in some environments, but not in all, so I cannot remove these variables from the script line. In Ansible 2.X, the default filter `|d()` is not necessary and the code can be written like this:

```
"{{ oracle1.instance.reports.forecast.email|d('testing@gmail.com') }}"
```

When running the script above, I am getting this error:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'reports'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/ansible/svn/stable-1.6-ansible2_other/playbooks/buildEnvironment/temp2.yml': line 21, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n      ignore_errors: false\n    - debug:\n      ^ here\n"}

Any help on this matter or how to use default variable filters for Ansible 2.X would be much appreciated!

Comment: "*Prior to Ansible 2.0, default filters were allowed*" -- really? What version does your template resolve successfully on? I just tried with 1.9.5 and it fails with `template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got '.'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it like this:

```
"{{ ((((oracle1 | default({})).instance | default({})).reports | default({})).forecast | default({})).email | default('testing@gmail.com') }}"
```