# How to check whether variable is defined, when dictionary may be missing in ansible/j2

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a Ansible and Jinja2 related question. I have an yml file like this:

```
---
haproxy:
  global:
    maxconn: 30000
    ssl: true
  defaults:
    maxconn: 400
  server:
    maxconn: 200
    httpclose: true
  frontend:
    web:
      maxconn: 20000
      ssl: true
```

In J2 template, I want to do something like this:

```
{% if haproxy.frontend.web.maxconn is defined  %}
    maxconn {{ haproxy.frontend.web.maxconn }}
{% endif %}
```

This works well, when the value is defined, but we use several environments and in some of them, the `frontend` dictionary is not defined (then, it will fall under defaults in haproxy, which is fine in dev) and when `frontend` is missing I get this error in ansible:

```
"msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'frontend'"
```

This error is produced by the if itself, not the body.

I know that the `frontend` does not exists, but that logically means the variable is undefined  (as it does not exists at all). Please, tell me how can I check for existence / definition of variable, when its dictionary can be missing.

Thanks!

P.S. Please, dont tell me to do something like

```
{% if haproxy.frontend is defined and haproxy.frontend.web is defined and haproxy.frontend.web.maxconn is defined %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conditional from "P.S." won't work for the same reason that your original one doesn't.

You'd need to use separate conditionals in nested statements:

```
{% if haproxy.frontend is defined %}
  {%- if haproxy.frontend.web is defined %}
    {%- if haproxy.frontend.web.maxconn is defined %}
      maxconn {{ haproxy.frontend.web.maxconn }}
    {%- endif %}
  {%- endif %}
{% endif %}"
```

---

What will work otherwise is an ugly construct with nested [`default` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#default) (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42826648/2947502)).

Here's an adaptation to your case:

```
{% if ((haproxy.frontend|default({})).web|default({})).maxconn is defined %}
    maxconn {{ haproxy.frontend.web.maxconn }}
{% endif %}"
```

or with `in` operator:

```
{% if 'maxconn' in (haproxy.frontend|default({})).web|default({}) %}
    maxconn {{ haproxy.frontend.web.maxconn }}
{% endif %}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The below also works if you're sure abc.cde is never undefined:

```
{% if "xyz" in abc.cde %}
      storageClassName: {{ abc.cde.xyz }}
{% endif %}
```